# Font in iOS11 is incorrectly displayed

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I have a font called Poppins-bold (you can find it on Google Font) that in iOS 11 display incorrectly. Here you can see a screenshot with iOS 10:

[image: iOS 10 Screenshot]

And screenshot in iOS 11:

[image: iOS 11 Screenshot]

Four fonts displayed are:

- Poppins Bold with a Storyboard
- Helvetica Bold with a Storyboard
- Poppins Regular via code
- Poppins Bold via code

And my error is with Poppins Bold via code. My code is:

```
label1.font = UIFont(name: "Poppins-Regular", size: 30)
label2.font = UIFont(name: "Poppins", size: 30)
```

How is it possible?

I've printed font in the projects and this is my result:

> Font Family Name = [Poppins]
>   Font Names = [["Poppins-Regular", "Poppins"]]

Comment: Hi Matt! I've printed all my fonts with this result: Font Family Name = [Poppins] Font Names = [["Poppins-Regular", "Poppins"]]. If I use Poppins-Bold it doesn't work both on iOS 10 and iOS 11. If I use Poppins it works on iOS 10 but no in iOS 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your printout explains the problem. "Poppins" is a family name. If you have both Poppins Regular and Poppins Bold, the family name defaults to meaning the regular font. This prevents you from accessing the Poppins Bold font by its name, which (unfortunately) is "Poppins".

Instead, use the font descriptor to change Poppins Regular to Poppins Bold:

```
    let font = UIFont(name: "Poppins-Regular", size: 30)!
    let desc = font.fontDescriptor
    let desc2 = desc.withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold)!
    let font2 = UIFont(descriptor: desc2, size: 0)
    self.lab.font = font2
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late, but in case your question is still relevant, problem can be solved by updating font files from https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins. You will also need to use "Poppins-Bold" font name instead of "Poppins".